# Shut down Windows 8 from command line WITHOUT BANNER?

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

One can open the command line (cmd) and type

```
shutdown -s -t 1200
```

to shut down Windows 8 in 1200 seconds. However, an ugly banner appears over the whole screen 10 minutes before the shutdown! **Is there a way to avoid the banner showing up?**

[image]

Comment: I see no banner when I do this (except the notification in the tray(. Can you take a screen shot?

Comment: http://imgur.com/AKSMN

Answer (score 15):

In PowerShell, use:

```
timeout -t 1800; shutdown -s
```

Or in `cmd`, use:

```
timeout 1800 && shutdown -s
```

They will cause a delay of 1,800 seconds (30 minutes), then perform the shutdown.

Comment: You'll want to use `&&` rather than `&`. `&&` only executes the right hand side if the left hand side returns an errorlevel of 0 (i.e. successful execution). `&` will always execute the right hand side. The problem here is that `&` will execute the right hand side **even if you cancel the countdown** (with `Ctrl` + `C`), which is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a "wait" command to add before shutting down, instead of making `shutdown` do the waiting. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735285/how-to-wait-in-a-batch-script) question, this should do the trick:

> ping -n 1201 127.0.0.1 > nul && shutdown -s

Comment: This doesn't work as written. However, I figured out how to do it anyway. Good idea, I can't believe it hasn't occurred to me that there is a wait command on Windows (I'm used to Linux's shell, and made the bad assumption that Windows can't do anything).

Comment: If you could let me know what the correct syntax is it would be helpful for people who find this question.

Comment: I'm not sure. Probably `ping -n 1201 127.0.0.1 > nul; shutdown -s` But I added an alternative answer below. You can test by using `shutdown -s -t 10` in the command, and then immediately typing `shutdown -a` to abort the shutdown. EDIT: This might have failed for me because I used PowerShell!

Comment: FYI you don't need to use `ping` anymore to delay scripts/commands. Windows Vista and later have a built-in `timeout` command which achieves the same purpose in a less roundabout way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good utility in Sysinternals (now Microsoft) PSTools called psshutdown. I use it since Windows NT for remote shutdown. It can also do a local shutdown. To be honest, I didn't check the differences between psshutdown and shutdown. I think it's worth a try.

As per the delay, why not use the builtin scheduler? I am not familliar with powershell, but I believe that a script could be written that would get current date, time, add a desired interval ant then create a run once scheduled task to execute a shutdown.